# GoPhish Docker : no valid version found

Tags: docker, docker-volume, gophish

I'm running GoPhish with below docker command:

```
docker run -v $PWD/:/opt/gophish/db -p 3333:3333 -p 80:80 gophish/gophish
```

But getting below error:

```
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=error msg="no valid version found"
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=fatal msg="no valid version found"
```

Detail logs:

```
Runtime configuration: 
{
    "admin_server": {
        "listen_url": "0.0.0.0:3333",
        "use_tls": true,
        "cert_path": "gophish_admin.crt",
        "key_path": "gophish_admin.key"
    },
    "phish_server": {
        "listen_url": "0.0.0.0:80",
        "use_tls": false,
        "cert_path": "example.crt",
        "key_path": "example.key"
    },
    "db_name": "sqlite3",
    "db_path": "gophish.db",
    "migrations_prefix": "db/db_",
    "contact_address": "",
    "logging": {
        "filename": "",
        "level": ""
    }
}
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=warning msg="No contact address has been configured."
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=warning msg="Please consider adding a contact_address entry in your config.json"
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=error msg="no valid version found"
time="2021-03-22T22:01:24Z" level=fatal msg="no valid version found"
```

I'm using official GoPhish image from Docker hub, not changing anything.

When I run `docker run -v $PWD/:/opt/gophish -p 3333:3333 -p 80:80 gophish/gophish`

its giving other error where container itself is not getting started :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "./docker/run.sh": stat ./docker/run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 0):

GoPhish is looking for corresponding db folder also when mounting volume. After installing GoPhish locally and setting correct path as below:

```
docker run -v $PWD/gophish/db:/opt/gophish/db -p 3333:3333 -p 80:80 gophish/gophish
```

Make sure you have all DB script in place otherwise it leads to another errors. For reference : https://github.com/gophish/gophish/tree/master/db